# Filter features within bounding box on provider side

Tags: qgis, sql, filter

I have a large polygon layer and want to filter only the features within a given bounding box (a other layer), BOFORE loading it into QGIS (on provider side). I tryed it with a SQL virtual layer but that consumes a lot of time:

```
select a.geometry, b.geometry from PolygonLayer a, BoundingBoxLayer b where ST_within(a.geometry,ST_envelope(b.geometry))
```

Is there a other faster and better way?

Currently I am using an Oracle DB as provider, but will be migrated to PostGIS in future.

Comment: Oracle for now, but will be migrated to PostGIS in future

Comment: How many features are in your BoundingBoxLayer?

Comment: up 100.000 features in BoudingBox, out of a total of 10.000.000 features

Comment: Thanks. And did you want to test if the polygons are within any of the individual bounding boxes of the 100,000 objects in the bounding box layer, or did you want a single bounding box enclosing all 100,000 objects? Does that make sense?

Comment: it can be more then one bounding boxes. The BB's are the envelop of country's shapes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an Oracle query which uses the individual bounding boxes, like your virtual layer query (you may need to prefix the table names with a schema name):

```
SELECT a.* FROM PolygonLayer a, BoundingBoxLayer b 
    WHERE ST_INSIDE(a.GEOMETRY,SDO_MBR(b.GEOMETRY))='TRUE'
```

and here is the same query with the geometry criteria flipped from WITHIN to CONTAINS , which may or may not run faster depending on which spatial indexes are used:

```
SELECT a.* FROM PolygonLayer a, BoundingBoxLayer b 
    WHERE SDO_CONTAINS(SDO_MBR(b.GEOMETRY),a.GEOMETRY)='TRUE'
```

And here is one which creates a single bounding box for all the objects in the `BoundingBoxLayer` layer and then selects the rows from PolygonLayer which are within that bounding box.  This query should be quite snappy, although the results may include lots more rows than you want :

```
SELECT * FROM PolygonLayer a 
    WHERE ST_INSIDE(a.GEOMETRY,(SELECT SDO_AGGR_MBR(BoundingBoxLayer.GEOMETRY) AS GEOM FROM BoundingBoxLayer))='TRUE'
```

Now how to make use of these queries to filter the results on the server before loading in QGIS?
I just realised I don't know how to express this as a ***Provider specific filter expression*** in the Layer Properties Query Builder.
[image]

I'm thinking maybe use the query to return a list of ids and filter against that - something like:

```
"id" IN (SELECT a.id FROM PolygonLayer a, BoundingBoxLayer b 
    WHERE ST_INSIDE(a.GEOMETRY,SDO_MBR(b.GEOMETRY))='TRUE')
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for a way to filter one layer by the geometry of another layer.

After reading M Bain's answer and looking through Oracle [Spatial User's Guide and Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/inter.817/a85337/sdo_objq.htm#871809) I was able to come up with the folowing code:

```sql
ID IN (
  SELECT a.ID
  FROM
    schema.PolygonLayer a,
    schema.BoundingBoxLayer b
  WHERE
    b.ID = 123
    AND SDO_RELATE(a.GEOMETRY, b.GEOMETRY, 'mask=anyinteract')='TRUE'
)
```

This code worked really fast. Remember to change the `b.ID` number to the **id** of the feature of interest.